# PrismaClientKnownRequestError: Invalid `prisma.post.create()` invocation (Typescript, Express, PrismaORM)

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express, prisma

Help me please, I already try to use GET and it works, but when I use POST always error with code error :

**On VSCode:**

> PrismaClientKnownRequestError: Invalid `prisma.post.create()` invocation

**On Postman:**

> POST http://localhost:3008/post Error: read ECONNRESET

and this is my code :

```
app.get('/feed', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    include: { author: true }
  })
  res.json(posts)
})

app.post('/post', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { content, authorEmail } = req.body
  const result = await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      content,
      author: { connect: { email: authorEmail } }
    }
  })
  res.json(result)
})


app.listen(3008, () =>
  console.log(`⚡️[Ihsanunot]: Server is running at https://localhost:3008`)
)
```

Prisma

```
model User {
  id        Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  email     String  @unique
  username  String  @unique
  name      String?
  posts     Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        Int       @default(autoincrement()) @id
  content   String
  author    User?     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int?
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
}
```

I am creating an app with typescript express node PrismaORM.
I can't POST to postman and beekepper, and in postgres is hidden.

Comment: I suggest wrapping prisma.create function in a try catch block and logging the error to see more details. This error means that the data for the prisma.create function are not valid.